# Como permitir quebra de linha no gridview?

Tags: asp.net

Fiz um teste no meu GridView escrevendo o titulo de um livro com muitos caracteres, o que aconteceu foi o seguinte: Ele expandiu meu grid além do tamanho da página, gerando uma quebra de layout. Meu GridView está com `Width="100%"`. Já tentei colocar na coluna `ItemStyle-Wrap="False"` mas não funcionou, como resolver?

[image: GridView com quebra de layout]

Comment: posta o código do seu grid.

Answer (score 1):

A solução é definir a seguinte propriedade na coluna que deseja que haja a quebra de linha:

```
 ItemStyle-Wrap="True"
```

Ou simplesmente não coloque propriedade nenhuma. O padrão do `GridView` do Asp.NET é fazer a quebra. Se quiser que **não** haja quebra, daí adicione a mesma propriedade mas com o valor `false`. Dessa forma, o HTML gerado para a coluna (`<td>`) virá com a propriedade `style="white-space:nowrap;"`.

*Observação*: Pela imagem do seu teste nunca vai haver quebra pois você incluiu uma única palavra com centenas de caracteres ("AAAAAAAAA....."). Tente testar com um texto comprido, mas com palavras de tamanhos variados e coerentes com palavras que existam.